# Is the space and time dimensions in Schwarzschild metric orthogonal?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, vectors

Schwarzschild metric does not contain any cross-terms such as $dtd\phi$, does that mean that space and time coordinates are orthogonal to each other?
Should the dot product of any time vector with position (space) vector must be zero since $dt {dx}^i$ does not exist?

Comment: This looks more like a question about terminology to me. All physics is encoded in the metric tensor.

Comment: This depends on the choice of coordinates. In other coordinates you do have mixed terms. For example in Gullstrand-Painleve coordinates.

Comment: @MBN thank you! This answers my question. I believe choice of coordinates depends on the kind of problem being solved but eventually the end results must be same irrespective of the coordinates used. I mean some coordinates may give more information than any other however the results in same domain must always be same.